# How to set constraints for textfield and button in Xcode 10.1

Tags: swift, xcode, constraints

I want to set constrains to textfield and button, I want it to be like this
how can I set them?
I want them to be in the center bottom of view
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdpCb.png

Comment: That is quite simple a view. You would have tried something. Why don't you show us that and we'll pick it up from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the two views i.e. TextField / Label and Button in a Horizontal StackView and then set the constraints:

1. Bottom constraint of the stackview to be x points from the bottom of the view 
   [image]
2. Add the Horizontal center equal to horizontal center of the parent view
   [image]

To give some space between these you can set the Spacing in the Horizontal StackView
[image]